# What is the proper SCIM syntax for adding a custom property

Tags: scim

I am trying to extend the user model and add a new string property. If I understand, I can simply add it and return the value.

My question is how do I document this in the resource type endpoint. Currently we have just the basic scim implementation so we return

```
"Resources": [
{
    "name": "User",
    "description": "User Accounts",
    "endpoint": "/Users",
    "schema": "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User",
    "schemas": [
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:ResourceType"
    ],
    "id": "User",
   "meta": {
        "resourceType": "ResourceType",
        "location": "https://apidsw017086.docusignhq.com/v201411/scim/resourcetypes/user"
   }
}
```

Should I just add the attribute section and add the new attribute, or do I need to list all the default attributes as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in [RFC 7643 Section 3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7643#section-3.3), you need to define a new schema and specify that schema in the ResourceType "schemaExtensions". You can look at the [enterprise user schema extension](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7643#section-4.3) throughout the spec for an example of how to do this.

Example Resource Type Representation:

```
[
    {
         "schemas": ["urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:ResourceType"],
         "id": "User",
         "name": "User",
         "endpoint": "/Users",
         "description": "User Account",
         "schema": "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User",
         "schemaExtensions": [
           {
             "schema": "urn:your:user:extension:schema",
             "required": false
           }
         ],
         "meta": {
           "location": "https://example.com/v2/ResourceTypes/User",
           "resourceType": "ResourceType"
         }
    }
]
```

Example Resource Schema Representation:

```
[
    {
        "id": "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User",
        "schemas": [ "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:Schema" ],
        "name": "User",
        "description": "User Account",
        "attributes": [ {...} ]
    },
    {
        "id": "urn:your:user:extension:schema",
        "schemas": [ "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:Schema" ],
        "name": "Your Custom User Extension Name",
        "description": "Your Custom User Extension Description",
        "attributes": [ {...} ]
    }
]
```